# what is this sql statement doing? (mysql)

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @row := @row+1 AS rank, account_id, keyword, bid_amount ,timestamp
FROM bids WHERE keyword='programmers'
ORDER BY bid_amount DESC, timestamp ASC
) AS derived_table;
```

i saw this somewhere and i was wondering what the set does along with the @ sign and the :=

thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's creating a row number column.

`@row` is an integer variable. `:=` sets the variable for each row, taking the previous row's value of `@row`. So, you get a nicely incrementing column which tells you what number row you're on.

Comment: but from this set example its setting row to be equal to 0. then selecting that 0'th as rank. so is it basically selecting from the very beginning row?

Comment: i mean why not just do a simple  select id,column1,column2,... from table ??

Comment: @sarmenhbb It is for legibility of the output only.  If this returns a list of 300 rows, you can look at the middle of the list and say "this is the 150th highest bid_amount" without having to count the rows yourself.